# Create folders and move files with batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have in my downloads folder about 50 .txt files and I need to create 50 new folders with name of that .txt for each file and move them to that new folder.
Can it be done in batch-file or do you recommend something else? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: yes, it can be done in BAT. **Hints:** read `HELP FOR`, `HELP MKDIR` and `HELP MOVE`.

Comment: For the question: "Can it be done in .bat file or you recommend something else?" Yes it can be done in batch. Just search how to do that because there are plenty answers for that kind

Comment: thx, i just wanted to know is it possible

Answer (score 0):

this is solution for me what i needed

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt*') do (
if not "%%~fa"=="%~f0" (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
if exist "%%a" move "%%~na.*" "%%~na"
)
)
```